# Calculate PSNR of mulitple images in one go ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to find the PSNR of images and write them to a file.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i original_image_1.tiff -i "modified_image_1.tiff" -lavfi psnr=stats_file=psnr_logfile.txt -f null -
```

This works nicely but I have more than one image and would like to make the command work on all of them in one go and write the final output in one file.

The images are named `original_image_x.tiff` where `x` is the image number that is to be compared with `modified_image_x.tiff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the sequence pattern for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1):

```
ffmpeg -i modified_image_%d.tiff -i original_image_%d.tiff -lavfi "[0][1]psnr=stats_file=psnr_logfile.txt" -f null -
```

Note for the [psnr](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#psnr) filter input `[0]` should refer to the main video, and input `[1]` should refer to the reference video.